# Row Labels for SlickGrid

Tags: slickgrid

Is there a way to add row labels to slick grid?

I guess worst case, I could make a static first column but I was thinking there might be something built-in?

Comment: What do you mean by 'row labels'?

Comment: Just like it has column labels (the first row headers) I want labels on each row.

Answer (score 1):

Basically what you need is just a column which you can style and format as you wish with your label content, but the functionality that is currently missing from SlickGrid is support for fixed/frozen columns.  There are some forks that have attempted to implement it, but the implementation is incomplete.

Comment: Thanks.  The only problem is that I can still click on the row label cells and they change color.  Is there an easy way to prevent that?

Comment: Also, how can I make this column with the row numbers all one color (the same color as the header) and not alternate colors with each row?

Comment: Just style the cell.  See http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example4-model.html for an example.  Also, you can make it unselectable and non-editable and subscribe to the grid's onClick event to select a row when clicking on that cell.

Comment: Thanks.  I think I'm getting there.  Would you mind elaborating on how to subscribe to the onClick event and what I should do?

Comment: Greg, the example I pointed you to demonstrates how to handle grid events and how to select rows programatically.

Comment: I don't see anything for onclick in the example.  And I'm just wondering how to make it not select the label cells when clicked on.  I really can't seem to find where your example is doing that.

Comment: Perhaps http://mleibman.github.com/SlickGrid/examples/example7-events.html will be easier to read.  You can also specify "focusable: false" in the column definition.